# Create image views with circular selectors on touch in android

Tags: android

I have a requirement to create imageview(or any other controls) and achieve a circular selector when user touches it. I have seen it in many apps like Whatsapp. Here is a sample screenshot from an app which explains what i meant actually. Kindly help. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In layout.xml you have to annotate the clickable view with

```
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```

for the effect you describe. However, it does only work for devices with API 21 and above. For devices below API 21 you can use:

```
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```